# Exclude dependency from pom using Maven Publish Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, maven-publish, gradle-shadow-plugin

I use the following plugins:

```
id 'maven-publish'
id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.0.0"
```

my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    shadow gradleApi()
    shadow localGroovy()
    implementation 'com.example:lib:0.1.0'
```

my publishing block:

```
publishing {
    publications {
        pluginJar(MavenPublication) {  publication ->
            from project.shadow.component(publication)
            artifact sourceJar
        }
    }
}
```

When I run `publishToMavenLocal` task I can see that in result `pom.xml` contains a dependency that I do not want there.

Let's say it's:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
  <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

How I can configure `publications` block in order to get rid of this dependency from the `pom.xml` (and module) file?

Comment: How does that com.example.lib dependency look in your `build.gradle`?

Comment: @Michael updated my answer, my goal is to bundle this dependency into jar using shadow plugin (already done) and get rid of it from `pom.xml` / `module`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that since my library had one `runtime` dependency I could use the following:

```
components.java.withVariantsFromConfiguration(configurations.runtimeElements) {
    skip()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Dependencies in `pom.xml` populates from `apiElements` (`compile` scope) and `runtimeElements` (`runtime` scope) configurations. You can remove dependencies you want to exclude from `pom.xml` from this configurations.

Example (I will use Kotlin DSL because I'm not familiar with Groovy):

```kotlin
setOf("apiElements", "runtimeElements")
    .flatMap { configName -> configurations[configName].hierarchy }
    .forEach { configuration ->
        configuration.dependencies.removeIf { dependency ->
            dependency.name == "lib"
        }
    }
from(components["java"])
```

Convert this code to Groovy and paste it in your `publication` closure.